# Change value of column on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an example of Dataframe df:

```
  Col1        Col2
   a        "some string AXA some string "
   b        "some string2"
```

I would like to:
if df.Col2 contains "AXA" then change the value to 1, if not then change it to 0.
So I get:

```
  Col1        Col2
   a            1
   b            0
```

I've tried something like,

```
if "AXA" in df['Col2']:
    df['Col2'] = 1
```

or if I can do something like

```
df.loc[df['Col2'] contains "AXA"] = 1
```

Thank you for help !

Comment: I see you delete question 15 minutes before. Do you find some solution?

Comment: Yes I found the error in my code :)

Comment: ok, so good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for `boolean mask` and then cast to `int`:

```
print (df.Col2.str.contains('AXA'))
0     True
1    False
Name: Col2, dtype: bool


df['Col2'] = df.Col2.str.contains('AXA').astype(int)
print (df)
  Col1  Col2
0    a     1
1    b     0
```

EDIT: If need create output by 2 conditions, fastest is use double [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (df)
  Col1                         Col2
0    a  some string AXA some string
1    a  some string AXE some string
2    b                 some string2

df['Col2'] = np.where(df.Col2.str.contains('AXA'), 1,
             np.where(df.Col2.str.contains('AXE'), 2, 0))
print (df)
  Col1  Col2
0    a     1
1    a     2
2    b     0
```

Comment: It worked ! As a plus, if I want to have: AXA =1, AXE=2, other=0, I can use same method ?

Comment: It worked like a charm, waiting the cooldown to approve your answer